# EXTJS Context Menu showing up in wrong place

Tags: javascript, extjs

extjs context menu is showing up occaisionally in the wrong place. Top left of screen, sometimes all the way left-middle. A lot of times it shows up fine, but it's showing up in the wrong place enough that it's annoying.

here is the start to my menu code:

```
grid<?php echo $count; ?>.contextMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
id: 'gridCtxMenu<?php echo $count; ?>',
items: [ ...
```

Here is where i'm attaching the showAt to the menu button "#actions_button;

```
var action_button = 'actions_button' + <?php echo $count; ?>;

Ext.fly(action_button).on('click', function() {
    var xy = this.getXY();
    xy[1] += this.getHeight();
    grid<?php echo $count; ?>.contextMenu.showAt(xy);

});
```

Using extjs 3.2, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be necessary to see the whole code in order to properly analyze the problem.

One possible cause is that `Ext.fly` writes to a singleton. That is, at the time the 'click' handler is run, the flyweight object points to a different DOM node, not `action_button`. This means in turn that `this.getXY()` returns crap.

> http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.1/docs/?class=Ext#Ext-fly
>   ...the dom node can be overwritten by other code. ... Use this to make **one-time references** to DOM elements which are **not going to be accessed again** either by application code, or by Ext's classes.

Use `Ext.get(action_button)` or `Ext.fly(action_button, 'MYNAMESPACE')` instead.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Pumbaa80! Looks like that fixed my issue, and it makes sense why. :)